# Limit mouse rotation to specific degrees

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DIV that I rotate based on the mouse position, here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JqBZb/550/

And the JS:

```
var img = $('.image');
if(img.length > 0){
    var offset = img.offset();
    function mouse(evt){
        var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width()/2);
        var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height()/2);
        var mouse_x = evt.pageX; var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
        var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
        var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
        img.css('-webkit-transform-origin', '15px 50%');
        img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
        img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate('+degree+'deg)');
    }
    $(document).mousemove(mouse);
}
```

First of all I say the code is taken from another post. The problem is that I want to limit the rotation of the DIV 75 degrees.

I want to make that the DIV can't point behind itself. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

just add the following before you set the css:

```
if( Math.abs(degree) >= 75) { return; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JqBZb/551/